# What would be the S-parameters for an "ideal" shorted transmission line?

Tags: rf, transfer-function, transmission-line, s-parameters

I seem to remember that the shorted- vs open-transmission line reflection is out of phase by 180-degrees.  I'm new to the mathematics behind transmission line theory and I'm trying to figure out how that phase shift is represented in the scattering matrix.

I couldn't find a reference for this, hence this question, so please correct me if I'm wrong: I am guessing the S-parameters for an ideal open-circuit and ideal transmission line are as follows.  The values are in dB format, so "0" means no loss:

**Ideal Transmission Line**

```
S11: -INF+0j   S12: 0+0j
S21:    0+0j   S22: -INF+0j
```

**Ideal Open Transmission Line (ie, its been cut but is not shorted)**

```
S11:    0+0j   S12: -INF+0j
S21: -INF+0j   S22: 0+0j
```

**Questions:**

- What are the S-parameters for an ideal transmission line that is:

  1. Shorted at one end?
  2. Open at one end?
  3. Are #1 and #2 represented purely as S11?  It doesn't sound like S21 would play a part here.
- Does \$Z_0\$ play any part in the "ideal" case?

I would be interested to understand how the math for how this trivial circuit is represented to calculate the resulting S-parameter matrix.  If you know the details then a bit of help understanding the math to create the resulting matrix would be appreciated.

Comment: What length of t-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. s11=0
2. s11=0
3. Y.
   .  N

If the other end cannot be accessed then only s11 is relevant.